# Correct Sales Cloud life cycle understanding?

Tags: relationships, sales-cloud

I have created a flow diagram, to represent my Sales Cloud flow understanding.

- Can you all tell me whether this flow/understanding is proper?
- I fully didn't understand the need & working of Campaign Member object? Little help is needed here.

Please do tell me if something is missing to make it more understandable.

Also if you have much more detailed & simplified flow charts, please do share.

---

Blue - Lookup

Red - Master Detail
[image: 1]

Answer (score 4):

> Can you all tell me whether this flow/understanding is proper?

> Also if you have much more detailed & simplified flow charts, please do share.

You can see the precise ERD (Entity Relationship Diagram) for [Sales Cloud](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/architecture-gallery/sales-cloud-overview-data-model). You're missing a few entities that are part of the Sales Cloud, but most of your understanding is correct. Checking out the above link should help.

> I fully didn't understand the need & working of Campaign Member object? Little help is needed here.

Campaigns are used to track marketing efforts. It can be used to ask questions like "which marketing strategies have the most ROI (Return On Investment)?",  "what are we doing wrong with our advertising?", etc. Campaign Members are Leads and Contacts that were generated through the campaign.

As a concrete example, Alice is on a news website, and sees an add for a Widget she wants to buy. She clicks on this ad and is taken to a site where she can get more information. These Widgets have a sales process though, perhaps because they can be customized or bought in bulk, whatever the case may be, and a Sales Associate needs to get involved. She fills out a form and is told she'll be contacted by someone soon.

At this point, the business now has Alice's data in Salesforce. We can see that she clicked on a specific ad, which is tracked by the News Widget Campaign, and her membership is a Campaign Member that is associated to her Lead record. We also probably have a Task for a Sales Associate to follow up with her.

After contacting Alice, the Sales Associate converts her to an Opportunity, which also generates an Account and Contact, if necessary. If we look at her now, we can see the Campaign Member was updated, the new Opportunity is associated to the Campaign, and its potential revenue shows up as part of the Campaign's calculated values. We can also see the associated conversations the Sales Associate has had with Alice.

Presuming that Alice then completes the purchase, and the Opportunity is Closed/Won, the Campaign now shows that some revenue was generated, and we can tell what the Return On Investment was. For example, if the news ad had a CPC (Cost Per Click) of $1, and the Opportunity was closed for $100, then the ROI would be 10,000%. Of course, only a small percentage of clicks will actually generate sales, so the real ROI will likely be a few hundred percent for most successful campaigns, but we're trying to keep it simple.

So, ultimately, Campaigns are a great insight to see how well your marketing department is doing, and this data can be used to try new strategies if the existing ones are failing, or where to expend more investment on campaigns that are successful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reading & answering my question. I had actually checked the ERD, but found it complex. So created my own & wanted to know if I can trust this understanding.

Comment: @MohitKulkarni As I stated, your understanding is more or less accurate, at least better than most people who start using Salesforce seem to have at the beginning.